# Nautilus shortcuts keyboard dependent of language?

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I need to do these shortcuts keyboards into a script:

```
Select All (Ctrl+A)
Invert selection (Shift+Ctrl+I)
Reload (Ctrl+R)
```

My question is: Are the Nautilus shortcuts keyboard dependent of language?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Pandya Thanks a lot! Could you answer as new reply, then I can give you the points? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic & common (Universal) Keyboard shortcuts **should not be dependent** on language.

Programmer and Developer should kept in mind pre-defined shortcut.

For Detail about stable Keyboard shortcut visit [Gnome-Help.](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en)

For Further key-board layout with different language visit [wikipedia-page1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout) & Table of key-board shortcuts at [page2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts)